# some problems related to characteristic polynomial and rank.

Tags: linear-algebra

1. Let $A$ be a real $4 \times 4$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $p(t)=(t^2+1)^2$, then $A$ is diagonalizable over complex numbers, but not over real numbers. Is this statement true or false?

I know, if A is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$, then minimal polynomial must be  $ (t^2+1)$, i.e $A^2=-I$.But I can't further proceed.

2. Let $T:R^7 \rightarrow R^7$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2=O.$ Then what is the maximum value of  rank(T) ?
3. Let $T:R^5 \rightarrow R^5$ be a linear transformation such that $T^4(x)=O.$ Then what is the rank(T) ?

I have no idea about (2),(3).  Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. The first statement is false, your matrix is not diagonalizable over the real numbers since its eigenvalues are complex. However, it is not necessary diagonalizable over the complex either. Here is a counter example.

$$
A= \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
i & 1 & 0 &0 \\
0 & i & 0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & -i & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &-i
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In $2$ and $3$ use the fact that similarity preserve rank.

2. Again use Jordan form, this matrix is nilpotent and since $T^2=0$ a block Jordan have size smaller of equal to $2$, try to take it from here.
3. Again, the Jordan form is nilpotent and the maximal size of a block is smaller or equal to $4$. As in $2$ there are number of possibilities for the rank.

Comment: Strictly speaking, one should show that the counter example in 1 is similar to a *real* matrix $A$; which is the case: $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1&0\\-1&0&0&1\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is *similar* (over $\Bbb C$) to your example.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen , thanks for your important comment.